# Right align a <span> inside parent <p>

Tags: html, css

I want to right align new-line text to the right-hand side of a p.

This is a simplified version of my current code:

```css
p {
  text-align: center
}

span {
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<p>
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  <br />
  <span>-author</span>
</p>
```

But my span is still centered. If I use `float: right` it goes on the right, but it's not inline with the last character of the p tag. Setting a `max-width` isn't ideal because `lorem ipsum` can be any length.

Here's a jsfiddle current: https://jsfiddle.net/dxgs3u41/

How do I right-align my span with the last character of my p?

Comment: The span has no concept of where the text ends in the example you've given; it can be aligned with the rightmost part of the container, but not of the text. If you want to change that, you need to adjust how the width of the paragraph's container is calculated

Comment: @OliverRadini I see, and what if I'm not currently calculating any width? :)

Comment: Well, by _calculating_ I mean that it currently takes the full width, as it's `display: block` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-positional possibility but again, the paragraph needs to be `inline` not `display:block`.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

span {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
  <p>
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    <br />
    <span>-author</span>
  </p>
```

Comment: I would consider flexbox properties since you are using flexbox : https://jsfiddle.net/szL5abq8/1/

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem. The span can only align to the edge of the container, rather than the end of the line of text, so you need to adjust how you've setup your markup:

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p>
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    <br />
    <span>-author</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: margin auto has no effect in this case since it no more a block element

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, that was a bit of a leftover from when I was trying to solve that with margin

Comment: and text-align are also useless ... the span is positionned and the p is inline block

Answer (score 1):

Use `inline-block` element so that the container width will be the content width and you can center the whole container and then center text inside it.

```css
div {
  text-align: center
}
div > p {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  <br>
  <span>-author</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  <br>
  <span>-author</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked in code snippet but not on my env - maybe some boostrap conflict (not sure how much it would conflict or that if it's even relevant but for whatever reason - didn't go down in tinsel town) - will upvote as in vanilla site - would work

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that doesn' t require `flexbox`. I personally dont like flexbox (mostly because i think it is very complicated), so it's up to you!

```css
div {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: block;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    <br />
    <span>-author</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: div is a block element by default, margin auto is useless because it's by default 100% width ... text-align:center on p is useless because it's inline block ... make a span block element is not the best solution. Without flexbox here is the easiest solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52535426/8620333